# How to capture the node value in selected node changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created treeview in asp.net and C#. It works fine. But when you click + the following method will be called:

```
protected void TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate(object sender, 
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    PopulateSubLevel(Convert.ToInt32(e.Node.Value), e.Node);
}
```

But I need while click on node (ie after `+`) for example : `+football`.

Here I will have id for football. Right. So I need to capture that node value when clicking on football. so that I can call populatesublevel method. Because once clicked on football, it has to show on right side it's images as well as I need to expand it's tree on left side.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
TreeView1.SelectedNode.Value
```